# Mapear dados Json Angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Criei uma service para carregar uma API Json:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';


@Injectable()
export class PlanosService {
  //get Json Servicos
    planos: Object[] = [];
    constructor(http: Http) {
      http
      .get('https://api.carguruclub.com/v1/servicos')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(planos => {
        this.planos = planos;
        console.log(this.planos);
      }, erro => console.log(erro));
    }
}
```

No callback ele me retorna o objeto, mas minha dúvida é em como manipular para que consiga exibir seus campos em minha view.
Exemplo:

```
   {
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "5886f570f0d1fb003caea75b",
            "id": "lavagem_padrao",
            "name": "Lavagem Padrão",
            "desc": "Lavagem completa",
            "recommendation": "Carguru recomenda a lavagem Padrão se você procura a melhor lavagem básica do mundo. Inclui calibragem dos pneus e o nosso famoso checklist."
        }
    ]
}
```

Queria exibir o campo name do objeto Products: {{products.name}}
Mas travei em como fazer esta parte.
Agradeço desde já

Comment: `console.log(this.planos);` retorna o json que da pergunta? por quê está utilizando `.subscribe()` ao invés de `.then()`?

Comment: @mercador sim, ele retorna os objetos

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, mas não seria somente pegar o dado e interpolar na view ? No seu componente : 

` registro: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.itemSvc.getReg(id)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.registro = data
        console.log('Categoria Encontrada ' + JSON.stringify(data));
      });
  }

E depois na view {{ registro.campo_que_vc_quer_exibir }} 

Desculpe se eu não entendi.

Comment: tente trocar `planos: Object[] = [];` por `planos: any;` se der/não der certo me avise por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você já está atribuindo o valor do subscribe a uma variável no seu typescript, seria só chama-la na sua view

```
{{planos.id}}
```